# ld cannot find library even though ldconfig does (rust-sciter)

Tags: gcc, build, rust, ld, rust-cargo

I'm attempting to run the `rust-sciter` minimal example however the run command `cargo run --example minimal` is telling me the library `-lsciter-gtk-64` cannot be found.

However when I check `ldconfig -p | grep sciter` it returns just fine `libsciter-gtk-64.so (libc6, x86-64) => libsciter-gtk-64.so`.

I've also ran `ldd` on the `.so` file itself and all `sciter` dependencies were found as well.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Visit** https://sciter.com/download/ . Download Sciter SDK!! Unpack!

```
Linux: sciter/bin.gtk/libsciter-gtk-64.so
cp -a sciter/bin.gtk/libsciter-gtk-64.so /lib
```

I'm writing through an interpreter. Himself faced this.

With the rest of the files you will understand.

*To compile enough library!*

Comment: copy library in the same folder as your build. As sciter tries to find library in serval place like. 
1. Enviroment Variable
2. Path
3. Same folder

Comment: You can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but you need to configure it before starting, which is not very.